# Processing large files with django celery tasks

Tags: django, celery, large-files

My goal it to process a large CSV file using Celery that is uploaded through a Django form. When the file's size is less than `SETTINGS.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`, I can pass the form's `cleaned_data` variable to a celery task and read the file with:

```
@task
def taskFunction(cleaned_data):
    for line in csv.reader(cleaned_data['upload_file']):
        MyModel.objects.create(field=line[0])
```

However, when the file's size is greater than the above setting, I get the following error:

```
expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Where the stack trace shows the error occurring during pickle:

```
return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
```

It appears that when the uploaded file is read from a temporary file, pickle fails.

The simple solution to this problem is to increase the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`. However, I am curious if there is a better way to manage this issue?

Comment: A custom [Storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/) handler would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Save it to a temp file and pass the file name to celery instead. Delete after processing.

Comment: May the temporary file be deleted before celery worker processes it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... Clearly you can't delete the file before you read it. Don't use tempfile.mkstemp from the standard library because it might get deleted automatically and won't be readable by another user. Just create a regular file and delete it by hand when you're done processing it. Or if convenient use django.db.models.FileField

Comment: This solution works if celery runs on the same server as your main app. If you are running on other server, then consider uploading to a common storage like S3.